# Learn Python The Hard Way, Ex21, EC3

Tags: python

**Ex21, Extra Credit 3:** Once you have the formula worked out for the puzzle, get in there and see what happens when you modify the parts of the functions. Try to change it on purpose to make another value.

**My code:**

```
def add(a, b):
    print "ADDING %d + %d" % (a, b)
    return a + b

def subtract(a, b):
    print "SUBTRACTING %d - %d" % (a, b)
    return a - b

def multiply(a, b):
    print "MULTIPLYING %d * %d" % (a, b)
    return a * b

def divide(a, b):
    print "DIVIDING %d / %d" % (a, b)
    return a / b


print "Let's do some math with just functions!"

age = add(30, 5)
height = subtract(78, 4)
weight = multiply(90, 2)
iq = divide(100, 2)

print "Age: %d, Height: %d, Weight: %d, IQ: %d" % (age, height, weight, iq)



print "Here is a puzzle."


# new formula
what = add(height, subtract(weight, multiply(iq, divide(age, 2))))

# original formula
# what = add(age, subtract(height, multiply(weight, divide(iq, 2))))



print "That becomes: ", what, "Can you do it by hand?"
```

The new formula that I wrote for this exercise is under the comment # new formula. After writing it and running it I noticed that something odd is happening: the floating point in the division age / 2 is ignored.

**Question:** Why does Python ignore the floating point in age/2 (also further operations) and how can I make it to not ignore it?

Comment: @Keith Please, I'm trying the best I can to ask a question and learn something here. If you don't understand what I am asking please tell me and I'll edit it, or help me out by editing it. But if you don't want to help out, please stop posting not constructive comments in 10s after I posted the question. Thanks!

Comment: You're right, I apologize for my flippancy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `float()` will work for anything, but if what you want to convert is a constant an easier way is explicitly to include a decimal place; i.e., `divide(age, 2.)`. Only one operand needs to be a floating point number to make the output also a float.

(**Edit:** as J.F. points out below, my wording here is a bit sloppy: by "anything" I meant "both variables and constants". More generally `float()` will attempt to perform a sensible conversion to a float, but of course there are cases where such a conversion either is impossible or involves losing some information - see the comment for some examples.)

Comment: (Or, without the function, `age/2.`.)

Comment: note: `float()` won't work for anything e.g., `complex`, `decimal.Decimal`, `fractions.Fraction` (possible loss of precision).

Answer (score 5):

If you are not using python3, you have to begin your main python files with

```
from __future__ import division
```

to make `1/2 == 0.5`. Otherwise `1/2 == 0` (integer division, basically rounding down).

You can always use `1//2` to access integer division if for some reason you actually want it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using Python 2.x, is that right?  Division defaults to integer division unless either the numerator or denominator is a floating point number.  You could correct it in your divide method by changing it to `return float(a) / b`.

Answer (score 1):

Division of integers in Python 2.x returns an integer result by default. This was changed in Python 3. Either convert one of the numbers to floating-point using `float()` or else put `from __future__ import division` at the beginning of your script.

(They get up to exercise 21 in *Learn Python the Hard Way* without mentioning this lovable Python quirk?)